# MySQL - why different results between case when null and if is null?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, case

I have a query like:

```
SELECT IF(b.field IS NULL, c.field, b.field) as `field`
FROM aaaaa a
LEFT OUTER JOIN bbbbb b
    ON b.uid = a.b_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ccccc c
    ON c.uid = a.c_id;
```

this query works. my question is why does the previous query work when the following, using a `CASE`, does not:

```
SELECT 
    CASE b.field 
        WHEN NULL THEN c.field
        ELSE b.field
    END as `field`
FROM aaaaa a
LEFT OUTER JOIN bbbbb b
    ON b.uid = a.b_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ccccc c
    ON c.uid = a.c_id;
```

assume that either `aaaaa.b_id` or `aaaaa.c_id` will be null; never both and never neither. also assume foreign keys between `aaaaa`, `bbbbb`, and `ccccc` are all properly configured. mysql v5.1.60 on rehl x86_64

the first query properly returned results as expected, but when i use the `CASE`, i am only returned the values for when the `ELSE` is satisfied (no `c.field`s return, only `b.field`s). what gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because that form of `case` checks the condition `b.field = null`, and you can't compare null values that way.

Use this form of the `case` instead:

```
CASE
    WHEN b.field IS NULL THEN c.field
    ELSE b.field
END as `field`
```

You can also use `coalesce` for this:

```
COALESCE(b.field, c.field) as `field`
```

Or `ifnull`:

```
IFNULL(b.field, c.field) as `field`
```

Comment: COALESCE works perfectly! think i'll go that way, but I tried adding the "b.field IS" portion to the WHEN and it still didn't return the values as expected. coalesce and the if methods work, but i'm still curious what's up with the case!

Comment: @JonBest: That's strange, it should really work. Did you notice that it only has `CASE` and not `CASE b.field`?

Comment: good call...that's exactly what i was doing wrong! i hadn't noticed it needed to be CASE WHEN. so, what was i saying (in SQL) by having the `b.field` in between the case and when?

Comment: @JonBest: You would get the condition `b.field = b.field is null`, which can't be true for any value.